# is there any gem for picture matching in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, image-manipulation

*I am making a website in ROR. In which i want to do picture matching. Is there any gem for picture matching of similar pics.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [phasion](https://github.com/westonplatter/phashion) for similarity detection of images

```
require 'phashion'
img1 = Phashion::Image.new "image1.png"
img2 = Phashion::Image.new "image2.png"
img1.duplicate? img2
# => true
```

Phashion, by default, detects images as duplicates if hashes differ by 15 bits or less.

**Edit:** 
You can use [opencv](https://github.com/ruby-opencv/ruby-opencv) for face detection in an image

1. Extract the face region of both images using openCV
2. Now match the faces using phasion library

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. But here i am making a website for missing persons. if i lost someone i upload his/her picture. and if someone  find him/her he will upload his picture. when he upload the picture then picture matching algorithm runs. in this case pictures will not totally be same.

Comment: @MuhammadAbdullah extract face from image and then match